# Bash nested looping behaviour

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm having trouble with a nested loop. The code looks like this:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    num=0
    for i in $line; do
        eval a_${num}="\"$(echo $i)\""
        echo $a_0
        ((num=num+1))
    done
done < file
```

In the file there are many lines. Every line consists of 16 space separated values: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16

When I read each line in the file the first occurance of **i** should be set as the variable **a_0**

So when I echo this value, given there are **two** identical lines in the file it should read:

```
01
01
```

However this is what happens:

```
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
01
```

Instead of echoing twice it will iterate twice the number of values in the line - 16+16 times. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use an array to populate values and not a variable!

Answer (score 0):

After some time this code (almost) solved my problem:

```
file=`cat files.txt`

# read the lines in the file and store every line in variable as "line"
while read -r line; do
# declare an array variable from every space separated value in "line"
  declare -a arr=`echo $line`
# set counter to zero
  num=0
# now loop through the above array
  for i in ${arr[*]}; do
# set a variable as "a_$num" that equals the current value in array
  eval a_${num}="'\"$(echo $i)\"'"
# incremenate "num" by 1 
  ((num=num+1))
  done
# echo the first value in current line
  echo $a_0
done <<< $file
```

Now the result should have been:

```
01
01
```

.... but for some reason it is only echoed once even though there are two lines:

```
01
```

I can still use the script though. Could anyone solve the last bit it would be great!